# Formatting Mail body in C# while sending system generated mail

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to email from c# the problem is when iam formatting in my body 
 doesnt seem to be working there any solution where i can use this break line also i need to create table in mail body. Below is my code where the body1 is my body of email content.

```
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("something@gmail.com", "Name");

        const string fromPassword = "pwd123";
        const string subject = "System generated test mail ";
        string email = bind_email(analyst);

       string body1 = "Hi " + analyst.ToString();
        body1 = body1 + "<br/>";
        body1 = body1 + " This is system generated test mail for " + Session["TaskAssigned"].ToString();
        body1 = body1 + " To be competed before" + Session["Enddate"].ToString() + "<br/><br/> ";

       var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = fromAddress,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body1,
        })

        {
            message.To.Add(email);                
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

Comment: did you put isHtml=true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ust put IsBodyHtml =true in MailMessage Settings

```
mailMessage = new MailMessage()
                    {
                        From = new MailAddress(senderAddress),
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = message,
                        IsBodyHtml = true
                    };
```

> Use html tags instead of plain text inside message.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you didn't assign MailMessage.IsBodyHtml to true. You can format your body using a true html.

I used to format my generated email coming from html. First create a test.html:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>
                Hi #analyst#
                <br/>
                This is a system generated test mail for #task_assigned# to be completed before #enddate# 
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </p>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Then just replace the needed data.

Here's your code I edited:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("something@gmail.com", "Name");

const string fromPassword = "pwd123";
const string subject = "System generated test mail ";
string email = bind_email(analyst);

System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/test.html"));
string body1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
body1 = body1.Replace("#analyst#", analyst.ToString());
body1 = body1.Replace("#task_assigned#", Session["TaskAssigned"].ToString());
body1 = body1.Replace("#enddate#", Session["Enddate"].ToString());

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage()
{
    From = fromAddress,
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body1,
    IsBodyHtml = true
})

{
    message.To.Add(email);                
    smtp.Send(message);
}

Hope this helps
```